# Can I extend a widget?

Tags: widgets

I want to add some fields to the widget.xml file of a third-party module.
Can I rewrite this file?

I thought duplicating it but the original widget could be used too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can override it this link may help you- correct ans if helps.
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/add-your-own-widget-templates-to-widget-options/